# Styling Multiple Radio Buttons by modifying Ryan Fait's code

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox, radio-button, customization

I am a big fan of using Ryan Fait's "Styling Checkboxes and Radio Buttons" Code
[click here for demo](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/)

I have run into a bit of a snag. I'm creating a survey form that has two uses for Ryan code. The first use uses big happy buttons that ask if you are happy, indifferent or sad about the question asked. The second use is for a "Rate your experience from 0-10" where I'll need to use a DIFFERENT and much smaller radio button graphic.

I've gathered that each instance of the different radio buttons needs its own CSS and class name, but I've tried to modify Ryan's code on my own and 1) I'm not Einstein and 2) I'm in a terrible rush to get some other projects completed.  The way I've tried to make this happen I've put an IF statement in each clause (moving the background position) looking for the className (class="hugeButton" vs class="teenyWeeny").  I either get one of two results:

- The original LARGE buttons don't even show up anymore.
- When you click on any button they disappear

Is there anyone out there who knows how I would have to modify Ryan's code to:

1. Allow for multiple graphics and sizes
2. Check for make sure its only effecting the specified className
   element
3. Do my laundry and make me a sammich

If it can't do #3, I'll be OK with that.

Comment: Classic example of why we require content *in* the question. The link is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, and I can't believe I was so naive.

I had to distinguish the functions, it was still making all instances of radio buttons and select boxes all invisible, but the javascript was overwriting all the functions since they were all still named the same, e.g. Custom.init and Custom.init.

I renamed the 2nd version, CustomMini and then instead of a window onload function at the end of the script, I just placed a Custom.init and CustomMini.init at the bottom of the page and VOILA!

Two different custom radio buttons using the similar script.

I figure there's got to be a more dynamic way to do this, but for right now, it works, it's good.

Answer (score 1):

I would say download another copy of the script. In one js file, replace all instances of the word "styled" to your first class name and in the second js file, replace all instances of the word "styled" to your second class name. Adjust the icon heights in the files as necessary depending on the icons you want to use. Then like you said, create separate CSS classes. The checkboxes/radio buttons should not affect one another since they are using different scripts with different properties, I would think.

Comment: You would think. That was my first inkling, but for some reason, the first radio button instance, "styled1" all disappear, but all instances of "styled2" are there.  I'm thinking somehow, the second script is overwriting the first.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to touch the javascript - CSS rule overrides should work.

- Apply a class to an element that wraps the smaller set if radio buttons - often a fieldset is appropriate for this kind of thing.
- Add rules that apply the appropriate size and background image to only the elements within your new wrapper class.  For instance "fieldset.compact input { height: 14px }"